# Twilio, pause before sending the next message

Tags: twilio

I use this way to send messages:

```
$AccountSid = $options['twilio_sid'];
$AuthToken = $options['twilio_auth'];
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$from = $options['twilio_number'];

foreach ($mesages as $message) {

    $client->account->sms_messages->create(
        $from,
        $message['sms_notification'],
        $author_notification
    );
}
```

**How do I pause it for a number of seconds?**

All messages should be send at once but with a delay of a number of seconds from the moment when the script is running.

Do I have to change for something like this: http://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/twiml.html#pause ? If Yes how do I make it work inside my loop?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to put a bit of delay between sending each $message in $messages - so that the first one will be sent and then a couple seconds later another one will be sent?

Comment: The app is more complex. All messages should be send at once but like 30 sec later.

Comment: Hey! twilio employee here - You can always just add a pause within the loop, that way you can control the delay through your software.

Comment: Is this running in a web request or as a stand alone script?

Comment: Is in a web request. I can't add a pause within the script, because my app is within a WordPress plugin that I'm working and I have a option that delays for hours sending the message.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio employee here.

There is a much simpler way to do what you want to do, just add a [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) within your loop like this:

```
foreach ($mesages as $message) {


    $client->account->sms_messages->create(
        $from,
        $message['sms_notification'],
        $author_notification
    );

    //Add your pause here using sleep()
    sleep(30);

}
```

This way you can control the delay / sleep yourself!

Comment: I have in the plugin that I'm working on the option to delay sending the message in hours and seconds. I don't think is a good idea to stop the script running for like 10 hours. Do you think is reliable?

Comment: I wouldn't have a delay of 10 hours in there. I'd use a daemon or cron job if that was the case. For shorter delays there shouldn't be much issue with sleeping for 1-10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple delay you would use something like [sleep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php), however, if this is being run inside a web request you would probably want the web request to send a message to a background service that would then handle sending the message at a specific time.

I have not done much like this in PHP but if this is what you are after you may want to check out something like [beanstalk](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/)

I see that you mentioned you are running this in a wordpress plugin - if running an external service yourself is not an option you may want to look into some of the "cron" wordpress plugins to see if you could hack one in to doing what you need.

Comment: This is really bad. I did not expect to be so complicated to just add a delay on sending a message with Twilio.

Comment: I just checked the Twilio docs, it appears they always try to send sms immediately. If you google for "twilio sms schedule" you will find a number of people with a similar problem - it appears they all went the route of having a separate service handling the actual sending.

Answer (score 1):

There is a service called IronWorker that may work for you. (I'm in no way affiliated).

http://www.iron.io/worker

From the website: "IronWorker is a multi-language worker platform that runs tasks in the background, in parallel, and at massive scale."

You would basically host your code snippet to send a message with them and execute it with a call from your script.  You can set it to whatever delay you like.

`$worker->postScheduleSimple('SendSMS', $smsParams, 10)`

The service offers a free tier with decent usage limits.